# Styled component theme prop throwing error in production but not development

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a Styled component button which may or may not take a theme prop

```
  ${props =>
    props.theme &&
    props.theme.length > 0 &&
    buttonVariant(color.white, color[props.theme], color[props.theme])}
```

on localhost everything is fine, however when in production I get lots of errors similar to

```
Component 'styled.button' (.sc-cHGsZl) references the 'theme' prop in its styles but no theme was provided via prop or <ThemeProvider>.
```

Why may this be?

Comment: If `theme` prop does not come from a `ThemeProvider`, you should rename it since SC seems to be picky about it

Comment: Thank's i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your App with a ThemeProvider component. This worked for me, not sure why yet. Probably because ThemeProvider pass themes via ContextAPI to others components, providing the theme.